# change label text from another controller in titanium alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to change text of label and make its visiblity true from another controller.

win_drawer_governmentNotification.xml

```
<Label id="filterCount" text="2"></Label>
```

win_drawer_governmentNotification.tss

```
"#filterCount":{
borderRadius: 100,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: "#f26418",
left: 46,
color: "#fff",
backgroundColor: "#f26418",
top: 15,
width: "8%",
textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
verticalAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
visible : false,
font: {
    fontSize: Alloy.CFG.fonts.f_10,
    fontFamily: Alloy.CFG.font_family.calibri
}
```

},

Now I want to change text of label filterCount from another controller in a function 
I tried below code.

win_drawer_governmentNotification_filter.js

```
function applyFilter(e) {
var controller = Alloy.createController('win_drawer_governmentNotification');
Ti.API.info('controller = ' + controller);
var filterLabel = controller.filterCount;
Ti.API.info('filter label = ' + filterLabel);
Ti.App.fireEvent("win_drawer_governmentNotification:filterCount", {
    text : "1",
    visible : true
});
```

win_drawer_governmentNotification_filter.xml

```
<View id="view_apply_main" onClick="applyFilter">
  <View id="view_apply">
    <Label id="lbl_apply" text="APPLY FILTERS"/>
  </View>
</View>
```

I tried different solutions from stackoverflow still haven't found solution like in

win_drawer_governmentNotification_filter.js

```
controller.filterCount.text = "1";
controller.filterCount.visible = true;
```

Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong? I am new to titanium.
Thanks in advance.